# Trigger function without awaiting response?

Tags: command-line, threading

I'm running an e-commerce solution for a client and have to upload a .txt file to an FTP for each order. I need to trigger the function I wrote to do this every time an order comes in, but I'm not sure how to do it so that the end user doesn't have to wait on function to complete before continuing their session. It can take a bit for the file write and FTP upload to complete.

The code also was written to be run from the command-line, so a completely independent session wouldn't be a problem, and no data needs to be returned to the user.

I fear this may quickly get into threading and php extensions, which I may have to dive into, but I'm hoping there may be a simpler way.

Comment: Maybe creating a wp_cron event that looks in a folder for any files that need to be ftp'ed to the new server, and if so transfer the files over?

Answer (score 0):

Since the program can be run from the command-line and no response is needed, using exec() does the job.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

The first example in the comments (below) was used to run my command-line program on payment submission. The program launches and the user never awaits its completion. Shouldn't matter if your machine is Windows or otherwise.

```
function execInBackground($cmd) {
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){
        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r")); 
    }
    else {
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");  
    }
}
```

In my scenario, $cmd is 'php54 [directory/file.php] [program parameters]'.